# Replace a word from html file in Python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to read an HTML file , and replace a few word with an equivalent word that i have in an excel sheet.
following is my code.

```
import urllib
import xlrd


workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('polish.xlsx', encoding_override="cp1252")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
page = urllib.urlopen("source.html").read()

for x in range(0,96):

 if not type(worksheet.cell(x, 2).value) is float:
    print worksheet.cell(x, 2).value.encode("utf-8")
    print worksheet.cell(x, 3).value.encode("utf-8")

    page.replace(worksheet.cell(x, 2).value.encode("utf-8"), worksheet.cell(x, 3).value.encode("utf-8"))
print page
```

But the replace function is not working. The `page` variable does not show any change.How can i replace a text in HTML file?

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Where does that error occur?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "langscript.py", line 16, in <module>
    page.replace(worksheet.cell(x, 2).value, worksheet.cell(x, 3).value)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

Comment: Are you running this in a cmd.exe shell?  If yes: type `cp 1252` and press enter at the prompt, then re-run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Type cast your variables to string in the replace method.

```
fist_var = worksheet.cell(x, 2).value.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
second_var = worksheet.cell(x, 3).value.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
for x in range(0,90):
 page.encode('ascii', 'ignore').replace(first_var, second_var)
```

This should work. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already tried that. My content is not just ASCII values. I was getting the following error when i tried this - `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: then if possible escape those values using ""value.encode('ascii', 'ignore')"" and then try it.

Comment: Can you change that in your answer?

Comment: In this case will i be able to retain the non ASCII characters? I require them in the output

Comment: above code is giving following error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 29: ordinal not in range(128`

Comment: so i guess the values from the excel file are in unicode.. so u can give encode then in ascii first.